# How to set a cookie after the user has agreed to the terms and conditions form?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, cookies, onsubmit

My question is, how do I set a cookie after the user has agreed to the Terms and Conditions page?
I was going to add this code

```
<?php //Calculate 30 days in the future    
//seconds * minutes * hours * days + current time    
$inOneMonth = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 + time(); 
setcookie('lastVisit', date("G:i - m/d/y"), $inOneMonth); 
?>
```

To the below code, but depending on where I put it I either break the javascript or on page refresh the cookie is set (even though the terms and conditions have not been agreed to).

```
<?php
// Get the user's ultimate destination
$dest = $_GET['dest'];
// Show the terms and conditions page
//check for cookie
if(isset($_COOKIE['lastVisit']))
    $visit = $_COOKIE['lastVisit']; /* Add redirect later   document.location.href='http://<?php echo $dest; ?>';   add redirect code later*/
else
    echo "No cookies present-remove this msg later";
?>

<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>User Agreement</TITLE>
    <script language="javascript">

function valbutton(thisform) {
// validate myradiobuttons
  myOption = -1;
  for (i=thisform.myradiobutton.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
    if (thisform.myradiobutton[i].checked) {
      myOption = i;
    }
  }
  if (myOption == -1) {
   alert("You must choose either YES or NO");
   return false;
  }
  if (myOption == 0) {
   alert("You must agree to the Terms and Conditions to download");
   return false;
  }
  thisform.submit(); // this line submits the form after validation
}
</script>

  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <H1> Terms and Conditions </H1>
    <P>Before downloading you must agree to be bound by masking tape</P>
<form name="myform" action="http://<?php echo $dest; ?>"> 
<input type="radio" value="1st value" name="myradiobutton" />NO<br />
<input type="radio" value="2nd value" name="myradiobutton" />YES<br />
<input type="submit" name="submitit" onclick="valbutton(myform);return false;" value="ANSWER" />
</form>

  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

I'm sure this is an easy question, but I really don't know what I'm doing. Any tips are much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+set%C2%A0cookie

Comment: @fabrik I did a search before, but wasn't really sure where to start. I will take another look, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach to do this would be to evaluate/validate the input also on the server side.
Normally you NEED to do this anyways because of security reasons, Javascript validation is only for user friendliness, not for security! In your case there is no real user input and therefore no direct threat.

Validate the input as you usually do with PHP by accessing the $_POST array and validating different form fields as required. When the whole chain of validations is successful, set the cookie!

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will check out the $_POST array. I kind of thought I would need to do something with the php since the form doesn't validate with javascript turned off. Cheers :)

Comment: @moomoochoo: it's not just that it doesn't validate with js off, it's highly INSECURE not to validate on the server side!!! ALWAYS validate on the server side, js validation is second.

Comment: @moomoochoo: Was this answer helpful?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know (I'm a n00b -as I'm sure you have already guessed), but it has given me food for thought. I'll keep working at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

and one more thing...
look at your setcookie call:

```
setcookie('lastVisit', date("G:i - m/d/y"), $inOneMonth);
```

if think the right way is

```
setcookie('lastVisit', date("G:i - m/d/y", $inOneMonth));
```